# Insert text at the beginning of element inside a contenteditable container

Tags: javascript, range, selection, contenteditable

Example: http://jsbin.com/vixuse/1/

How I can use range object to solve this problem?

thanks in advance.

My code:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    Hello World <span>try to insert text in the beginning of this element</span>    
</div>
```

When user try to insert text in the beginning of span element, result:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    Hello World [INSERTED_TEXT]<span>try to insert text in the beginning of this element</span>    
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem is that you are having. This link offers almost no information.

Comment: I assume your downvoting was way to fast swestfall. The example shows clearly where to insert text.. At the beginning of the blue line.

Comment: In this example, the document is editable and I want to allow user to insert text inside blue element at the beginning of it. The problem is the inserted text going to insert before the blue element.

Comment: Please post your (minimal, [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) code that reproduces your problem into your question. Don't just link to an external resource (even though it's always a good idea to provide a demo, but only *as well as* the (relevant) code in your question).

Answer (score 0):

I just get one solution to solve your problem, but not with the Range Object.

**You can set the attribute `contenteditable=false` to the `div`, and then set the same attribute with `true` to the `span` you need to edit.**

As I don't know the specific use scene you need, my solution is just useful for your example.

If it is useless for your scene, don't downvoting me please.

**UPDATE**

In addition, if you still need `contenteditable=true` of your whole container, you could set `contenteditable=true` to the container(`body` or another tag), `false` to the tag of the line, and `true` to the tag you need to edit.

Here is the jsbin link: http://jsbin.com/jolopela/5/edit

Thanks,
Edison

Comment: the div container must be editable. The elements inside the container is formatted text.